# Match Array1 and Array2 values jQuery

Tags: arrays, match

I have absolutely no clue where to look for.. I have 2 arrays in jQuery and I want to combine the values together. As in: first value array one with first value array 2..
I have 2 arrays, example:

```
$arrayOne = 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'

$arrayTwo = '1', '2', '3', '4'
```

I want to combine these and get the following output

```
'A': '1',

'B': '2',

'C': '3',

'D': '4',
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Danny

Answer (score -1):

**Approach:** Loop over the array whose value you want as a key & then push one by one key value pair objects into a map object which is has to declare above the loop.

**Note:** Both arrays should have the same number of elements.

**Code:**

```
$arrayOne = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
$arrayTwo = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
var arrayToMap = new Object(); // or var map = {};
$arrayOne.forEach(function( value, index ) {
  arrayToMap[value] = $arrayTwo[index];
});
console.log(arrayToMap);
```

**Output:**

```
{A: "1", B: "2", C: "3", D: "4"}
```

You can refer the following link if you are new to the array list + loops:
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: Please don't just dump code and explain your answer, providing links to documentation for further reading of the OP.